# How to build freetype on Cent OS 6.5?

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to build the freetype library I got from here: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz But I am really failing to do so.

I am using Cent OS 6.5, and the compiler is g++ 4.8.2. I need the library to be release, static and 64 bit. Is there anyone who can explain this in simple steps, please?

I am trying to compile my program and I am getting an error telling me I need some freetype .so file.

Comment: `./configure; make; sudo make install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before building it myself, I would try

```
yum install freetype2-devel
```

If that doesn't install the library you need, you can try `configure` with something like (enable-static for static build and the [target triplet](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html))

```
./configure --enable-static x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Then you can build it by running

```
make
```

Finally, you can install it by running

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Do I need to add a setting to get the 64bit version, or all build are the same?

Comment: @SpeedCoder Edited. Make sure you are running on a 64-bit system, `uname -i` should be x86_64

Comment: Thanks, one final thing, instead of `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` to be sure it's ok, is there any cent os specific setting? Like `el6.x86_64`

Comment: I believe that is the target triplet you need (you can certainly put centos in somewhere, but I wouldn't because you aren't centos). The recommended approach is to use rpm (or the srpm) and not fiddle with it without packages. The default installation path for this is `/usr/local` so it should be safe enough (especially if you're linking statically); but I would first try using a packaged version and a dynamic library.

Comment: You mean there is a risk of crashes due to incompatibility because I am building from source and not using the RPM? I am building from source to be sure it's the latest version and not modified.

Comment: There's always that risk even if you use the RPM, no I mean your application will be less efficient then it needs to be (especially if there are multiple users using it simultaneously). Also, you are then responsible for upgrading your library, maintaining it, etc. If it's been modified by the distribution there's probably a reason.

Comment: One last thing: I am getting a small warning: `configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target` is there a quick fix?

Comment: Yes. First, it's a warning. And replace the singular `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` with `--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` and the warning will go away.